# What is Winston Zeddemore's doctorate in?

Tags: video-games, ghostbusters

On the Wiki page for Winston Zeddemore it implies he has a Doctorate (which is started studying for sometime after the second film)

> As previously mentioned, Ernie Hudson reprised his role as Winston Zeddemore for 2009's Ghostbusters: The Video Game, with both Hudson's appearance and voice being used for Zeddemore in the game. **Furthermore, since the events of the first film sequel, Zeddemore has earned a Doctorate and is now addressed as "Doctor" along with his colleagues** (this is a possible callback by series co-creator Dan Aykroyd to the film Spies Like Us). During battles on multiplayer, Zeddemore can be heard quipping "That's Dr. Zeddemore to you, punk!" when defeating enemies suggesting that he successfully completed his PhD.
> ~[Winston Zeddemore: Role in Video Games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winston_Zeddemore#Role_in_video_games)

This section is uncited but this fact is either mentioned in the video games or is left unanswered. Which is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've been unable to find an actual quote regarding the specifics of his doctorate, but the canon reference is that Winston practically lived in the **Egypt Exhibit** at the "*Museum of (Super)Natural History*" in [Ghostbusters : The Video Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostbusters:_The_Video_Game) so it's fairly reasonable to assume his PhD is related to **Ancient History**, potentially with some kind of slant on the supernatural.

[image: Screenshot from the Ghostbusters video game. The scene is an ancient Egyptian museum exhibit; the viewpoint is behind and slightly above Winston's right shoulder, with his back in the left foreground. Over his left shoulder is a large statue of a god on a pedestal, and another god statue stands partially behind a Doric column to its right. On the right side of the frame is the base of an exhibit with a small card and upward-directed lights. Central, and opposite Winston, is a sarcophagus exhibited in front of the reconstruction of the exterior of a temple.]

It's also worth noting that in the original scripts, Winston is less of an everyman character and more of an all-American hero, with a very substantial background in the military.

[image: This scan of a portion of the script reads: STANTZ: "What'd you do in the service?" WINSTON: "Five years, U.S. Air Force Air Police. I mustered out as Captain assigned to administer perimeter security at Reese Strategic Air Command Base...from there I designed electronic barrier systems for Sentry Alarms and I ended up as V.P. Tactics and Training at their Pacific Headquarters...until they closed the offices there." STANTZ: "Wow. Impressive. It's just that, well, when we advertised for a security man we really meant something more like a guard...you know, dirty work with a fair amount of risk." WINSTON: "I have a fifteenth degree black belt in Wing Chun boxing and I am a qualified, award-winning weapons handler. What kind of risk are you talking about?"]

Comment: Fifteenth degree black belt? As far as I can tell Wing Chun doesn't even really *have* an official belt system.

Comment: @JackBNimble - Don't let him hear you saying that...

Comment: We will just call him the Jean Claude Van Dame of the Ghostbusters world.

Comment: I need to play this game, it keeps popping up in answers.

Comment: I want a game where this Winston and the canon Winston team up to bust ghosts together!